# sql server-percentage calculation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Sample data :**

```
LINE_NO E_FIELD F_FIELD G_FIELD HSA_STATUS  FAMILY  CACHE_FAMILY    Count
23053B  00000   00000   00000   S           SUMMIT      WER           43
23053B  00000   00000   00000   T           SUMMIT      WER           144
23053B  00000   00000   00684   T           SUMMIT      WER           2
23053B  00353   00418   00684   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   00763   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   01512   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   06797   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   30228   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   31935   T           SUMMIT      WER           2
23053B  05601   01402   00758   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  05601   01402   09091   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  05601   01402   65053   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT LINE_NO,
  E_FIELD,
  F_FIELD,
  G_FIELD,
  HSA_STATUS,
  FAMILY,
  CACHE_FAMILY,
  Count = ((SUM(TOTAL)) )  
FROM
(
  SELECT LINE_NO,
    E_FIELD,
    F_FIELD,G_FIELD,
    HSA_STATUS,
    FAMILY,
    CACHE_FAMILY, 
    Count(LINE_NO) as Total 
  FROM TX_HSA_SUMM 
  WHERE MT_TIMESTAMP2 BETWEEN ('2013-03-07 10:10:00') AND ('2013-03-08 10:20:00') 
  GROUP BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY
) as a
GROUP BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY,total
ORDER BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY,total
```

This is my sample data actually. I already make the count. As You can see the column header. My problem is I need to sum the count and the for each row I need to get the percentage. For example the total for the above record is **199** so for the first record count is **43** so the calculation should be **43/199 * 100**. How can I view the percentage? Please help me I need this urgently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of how the Window Functions can be used. Based on your data, I'm assuming you want to do this for every unique LINE_NO. I'll leave it to you to format the percentage column.

```
SELECT      LINE_NO,
            E_FIELD,
            F_FIELD,
            G_FIELD,
            HSA_STATUS,
            FAMILY,
            CACHE_FAMILY,
            COUNT(*) AS CT,
            COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*) * 1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY LINE_NO)

FROM        TX_HSA_SUMM

GROUP BY    LINE_NO,
            E_FIELD,
            F_FIELD,
            G_FIELD,
            HSA_STATUS,
            FAMILY,
            CACHE_FAMILY
```

Comment: The `Count` column is not part of the sample *data*, even though the OP included it in that section.

Comment: Jon - ah, you are correct, I missed that at first. I tweaked the query, I believe that should get the OP what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I believe is you can wrap around your statement with another SELECT statement and do Count / SUM(Count) * 100 to get your percentage column. Hope that makes sense.

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
create table #results (LINE_NO VARCHAR(50), E_FIELD VARCHAR(50), F_FIELD VARCHAR(50), G_FIELD VARCHAR(50), HSA_STATUS VARCHAR(50), FAMILY VARCHAR(50), CACHE_FAMILY VARCHAR(50), Count INT)

insert into #results
    SELECT LINE_NO,
  E_FIELD,
  F_FIELD,
  G_FIELD,
  HSA_STATUS,
  FAMILY,
  CACHE_FAMILY,
  Count = ((SUM(TOTAL)) )  
FROM
(
  SELECT LINE_NO,
    E_FIELD,
    F_FIELD,G_FIELD,
    HSA_STATUS,
    FAMILY,
    CACHE_FAMILY, 
    Count(LINE_NO) as Total 
  FROM TX_HSA_SUMM 
  WHERE MT_TIMESTAMP2 BETWEEN ('2013-03-07 10:10:00') AND ('2013-03-08 10:20:00') 
  GROUP BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY
) as a
GROUP BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY,total
ORDER BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY,total

declare @totalcnt int
select @totalcnt = sum(count) from #results

select *, (count / cast(@totalcnt as float)) * 100 as CountPercent from #results
```

That should give you the additional column with percentage values per row.

Comment: i have do that also but when i reduce the number of columns im getting only the total count that is the problem.